# management attribute is missing in the Goals

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics-api

When I try to run the code, I have the service object. Does the api still valid or am I missing something?

```
# Example #1:
# Requests a list of all goals for the authorized user.
try:
  goals = analytics.management().goals().list(
      accountId='~all',
      webPropertyId='~all',
      profileId='~all').execute()

except TypeError, error:
  # Handle errors in constructing a query.
  print ('There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error)

except HttpError, error:
  # Handle API errors.
  print ('There was an API error : %s : %s' %
         (error.resp.status, error.resp.reason()))
```

I get following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'management'
```

Comment: Also is this same Goals which are used in Google Calendar or is it different in analytics api?

Comment: example taken from here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals/list

Comment: I'm not seeing where your code comes from.  The closest I see is https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/samples/analytics/management_v3_reference.py  Are you sure you're using the right api?

Comment: I change the code a bit, with values of parameters to "~all" but the code is from this link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals/list and Example 1

Comment: You are checking a Universal analytics account correct?  Ga4 has a different structure and must be used via a different management api.

Comment: I'm looking to access Google calendar goals. Not sure if this is correct one or different? If it is different api which one is it?